# Отображение в cout уникальных рандомных чисел

Tags: c++, циклы, случайные-числа

Пробовал отсеивать через if, но не получилось. Поможете реализовать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;
int main()
{
tryAgain:
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    bool alreadyThere;
    int randNumber, quantity, selection;
    int fourNull = 0000;



    cout << "Выберите тип генерации" << endl
        << "1.Упорядоченный" << endl
        << "2.Рандомный" << endl;
    cin >> selection;

    switch (selection)
    {
    case 1:
        cout << "Выберите количество генерируемых номеров" << endl;
        cin >> quantity;
        alreadyThere = false;
        while (fourNull <= quantity)
        {
            fourNull++;
            cout << "+7910000" << setw(4) << setfill('0') << fourNull << "\t\t";

        }
        goto tryAgain;
        break;

    case 2:
        cout << "Выберите количество генерируемых номеров" << endl;
        cin >> quantity;
        for (int i = 0; i <= quantity; i++)
        {



            randNumber = rand() %9999 + fourNull;
            cout << "+7910000" << setw(4) << setfill('0') << randNumber << "\t\t";



        }
        goto tryAgain;
        break;

    default:
        goto tryAgain;
        break;

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что-то тут не видно никаких попыток их отсеивать, даже упомянутого `if` нет.

Comment: Я стёр этот позор)

Comment: Может, стоит просто взять массив с числами от 1 до нужного (у вас 9999), перетасовать его и выводить первые quantity чисел?

Comment: Хорошо, попробую

Comment: Вы понимаете, что нет никакой разницы между `0000` и `0`? Везде, где вы написали `fourNull` можно было просто поставить `0`, эффект был бы такой же.

Comment: Я совсем недавно начал изучать программирование,изначально проблема была в том, что в выводе отображались 7...10-ти значные цифры вместо 11-ти, проблема была решена с помощью << setw(4) << setfill('0') , но спасибо, действительно, можно обойтись и одним нулём.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void unique_random_numbers(int min, int max, int amt)
{
    std::map<int, int> m;
    int  r{}, count{}, range = max - min + 1;
    while (count < amt) {
        r = min + rand()% range;
        //или пользуйтесь  генераторами случайных чисел из <random>
        m[r]++;            
        if(m[r] == 1) {
            ++count;
            cout << r <<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Вызовите функцию с аргументами:

1. Минимальное значение чисел
2. Максимальное значение чисел
3. Количество уникальных чисел, которые хотите выводить